# jQuery - Submit Form... but also pass submit input name and ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following jQuery code, which automatically submits my form whenever the user selects a file to upload in the file input field:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function () { 
    jQuery(this).parents('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="bp_avatar_upload" />').submit();
});
```

However, I also need to pass along the ID and name of the submit input with this code. The ID and name for the submit input are both `upload`, as seen in the original, non-jQuery code:

```
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload Image" />
```

Please advise how I may be able to go about this. Very much appreciative of all help on this!

Comment: Append it the same way?

Comment: Tried that.. Doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: Even if you set `type="hidden"`?

Comment: No luck with that adjustment :-(

Comment: It really makes no sense - are you sure there's no code from the plugin you're using that also overrides the submit function?

Comment: @Shomz, you are spot on... I had left additional code from the plugin that was interfering with the form. By removing it, setting the submit input to `hidden` and giving it another go.. it works! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a basic hidden field within your form as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
```

Then Change its value on image Selection while submitting form at same time:

```
$("#upload").change(function(){
document.getElementById("action").value = "bp_avatar_upload";
$("#form").submit();
});
```